# Getting frame from all (visible and invisibles) UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an `UICollectionView` with 30 items of `UICollectionViewCell` inside. There are 8 cells which are currently visible to the screen, the rest are pretty much invisible. I'm able to get the frame value from all of those visible cells.

My question is what should I do to get frame value from all cells, including the invisible one.

This is my code.

```
// some code before

for (int i = 0; i < [collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0]; i++) {
    cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    if (!cell) {
        [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
            [collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
            [collectionView reloadData];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
            NSLog(@"- after batch update %d %@", i, NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
        }];
    }
    NSLog(@"- %d %@", i, NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
}

// another long code
```

The results was, I'm able to get right frame of first 8 cells. The next cells (the one which are invisible) have wrong frame.

This is the log:

```
2013-07-08 16:38:57.904 My App[71245:c07] - 0 {{2, 2}, {217, 326}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.905 My App[71245:c07] - 1 {{231, 2}, {217, 326}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.906 My App[71245:c07] - 2 {{460, 2}, {217, 326}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.906 My App[71245:c07] - 3 {{689, 2}, {217, 315}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.907 My App[71245:c07] - 4 {{689, 340}, {217, 326}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.909 My App[71245:c07] - 5 {{2, 340}, {217, 329}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.909 My App[71245:c07] - 6 {{231, 340}, {217, 315}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.910 My App[71245:c07] - 7 {{460, 340}, {217, 286}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.910 My App[71245:c07] - 8 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.911 My App[71245:c07] - 9 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.911 My App[71245:c07] - 10 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.912 My App[71245:c07] - 11 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.912 My App[71245:c07] - 12 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.913 My App[71245:c07] - 13 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.913 My App[71245:c07] - 14 {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.904 My App[71245:c07] - after batch update 8 {{689, 640}, {217, 326}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.905 My App[71245:c07] - after batch update 9 {{689, 640}, {217, 326}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.906 My App[71245:c07] - after batch update 10 {{2, 640}, {217, 326}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.906 My App[71245:c07] - after batch update 11 {{231, 640}, {217, 315}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.907 My App[71245:c07] - after batch update 12 {{460, 920}, {217, 326}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.909 My App[71245:c07] - after batch update 13 {{2, 920}, {217, 329}}
2013-07-08 16:38:57.909 My App[71245:c07] - after batch update 14 {{231, 920}, {217, 315}}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need to make cells visible to get their frame, the collection view manages the frames (and other layout attributes) in its `collectionViewLayout`, so you can get the frames from that.

```
NSInteger numberOfCells = [self.collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:0];
UICollectionViewLayout *layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < numberOfCells; i++) {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [layout layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0]];
    CGRect cellFrame = layoutAttributes.frame;
    NSLog(@"%i - %@", i, NSStringFromCGRect(cellFrame));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4 version** (extension for UICollectionView)

```
extension UICollectionView {

    func framesOfCells(inSection section: Int) -> [CGRect] {
        var frames: [CGRect] = []

        for item in 0..<numberOfItems(inSection: section) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item: item, section: section)

            if let attributes = collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath) {
                let frame = attributes.frame
                frames.append(frame)
            }
        }

        return frames
    }

}
```

Comment: In case someone doesn't want to make an extension, its `collectionView.collectionViewLayout.layoutAttributesForItem(...)`

Answer (score 2):

I was facing a similar problem when I needed to capture an image of a collection view whose cells extended beyond the visible rectangle.  I needed more than just the layout information on all the cells; I needed the system to actually draw the entire collection view.  I tried using the `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` method to programmatically sweep across the view to force drawing of the whole thing before capturing the image, but no luck.

The solution was, inside the image capture method, to set the collection view frame to match the entire content size and call `invalidate layout`, which forced the view to call for layout attributes for everything in the whole view.  After I captured the image, I restored the collection view to it's original UI size, and it worked perfectly:

```
- (UIImage *)getImageOfEntireCollectionView {

     // Store original CV frame and get content size
     CGPoint refCVOrigin = self.collectionView.frame.origin;
     CGSize refCVSize = self.collectionView.frame.size;
     CGSize contentSize = [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout collectionViewContentSize];

     // expand CV size to match content size and redraw it
     self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, contentSize.width, contentSize.height); 
     [self.layout invalidateLayout];
     [self.collectionView reloadData];

     // capture image of CV
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.collectionView.bounds.size);
     [self.collectionView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

     // restore original CV frame
     self.collectionView.frame = CGRectMake(refCVOrigin.x, refCVOrigin.y, refCVSize.width, refCVSize.height);

     return screenshot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UICollection view doesn't store Cells for every element in your collection. Only for visible ones. When you scroll you just reuse the ones that are already invisible. So you can't get properties of unexisting cells.

In MVC you need to work only with your data and visible cells which present part of the data. So what you're trying to do is conceptually wrong.

Comment: Yes, I know that, and that's why I use `[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:i inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];` for scrolling down getting the invisibles one. but I still cannot get the right value

Comment: What Tala is saying, is that, you will never have 30 instances of UICollectionViewCell, as there's only the amount needed to show inside the UICollectionView (and probably a few more). So if you try to get all of them, you will get several times the instance of the same cell.

Comment: @Raspu I don't need each of `UICollectionViewCell` instance. I'm just need to collect all of the frames

Comment: These frames will be meaningless. Depending on how user scrolls they will be different... Also since you scroll, and thus, channge the coordinate system start - frames will be highly intersecting each other

Comment: No, I need it. I've a tableview which contains 30 items (same value as my collection view items). Why I need those frames is because I want to create a transition animation from the visibles 30 items `UITableViewCell` to the 30 items of my collectionview

Comment: because you said _So what you're trying to do is conceptually wrong_. I can get the items by scrolling it first. And I can scroll it using `scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`

Comment: have you tried my code in the question? it's work well, I can get the items. My problem is not I can't get the items, but How should I do to get it without using `performBatchUpdates`. `performBatchUpdates` is non-blocking, I need the block one

Comment: The main concern I was talking about: that in your code you aren't working with 30 different cells, collection view reuses them and when you get frame for 15th cell, 1st and 2nd might already be reused and their frame doesn't exist any more.